# Cannot build with include Winhttp to Windows XP (v141_xp)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winhttp

I am using Virsual Studio 2017 and working on Win7 system, I having following code that using `Winhttp`:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <winhttp.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "Winhttp.lib")

int main(int argc, char *args[])

{
    return 0;
}
```

I can build it successful When Options -> Configration Properties -> General -> Platform Toolset is `Visual Studio 2017 (v141)`, But I cannot build with `Visual Studio 2017 - Windows XP (v141_xp)`

the build error following:

```
Error   C2760   syntax error: unexpected token 'identifier', expected 'type specifier'
```

[image]

If I remove `<Windows.h>` and `<winhttp.h>`, it will compile with successful.

Comment: Well, and you expect people to be able to look inside those header files? Just copy'n'paste their content and then keep removing stuff until you have a minimal example. BTW: XP is unsupported and doesn't receive any updates, so why would you need to build for it?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: That would probably be unhelpful. I assume the error is caused by the use of a modern SDK without XP support.

Comment: Even though "Visual Studio 2017 - Windows XP (v141_xp)" is selectable in the project settings, it seem like "Windows XP support for C++" is a separate item in the installer, not selected by default.

Comment: @BoPersson thanks, "Windows XP support for C++" is actually installed

Comment: What would be unhelpful, @MSalters? Providing a minimal example?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: The problem here is that the Win10 SDK probably misses some backward-compatibility defines for XP. You suggest copying the offending bits, but you can't copy _missing_ lines from a Win10 SDK.

Comment: No, I'm just suggesting to eleminate `stdafx.h` first and then descend into the other headers there. That way, we'd get the code that causes the error, which is the first step towards fixing it. Anyhow, there isn't even a question here (apart from the implied "how can i make my problemses go away??") so I'm voting to close this.

Answer (score 1):

For this case, you could try to add this statement to use forward declaration in you code.

```
#define CINTERFACE
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help someone else that stumbles on this question and has the same problem I had.  I was trying to target v141_xp as well because I needed to run C++14 code on Windows Server 2008 R2.  I never got that to work, the SDK 7 install for VS 2017 appears to be incomplete.  However, installing the VC 2017 redistributable package on Windows Server 2008 R2 did get my build to run when I set the Platform Toolset to v141 instead of v141_xp.  That's good enough for my use case.

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
Other Tools and Frameworks->Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2017